# Parse Json column values from csv using Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to parse json string column `additional_json` field serviceType in csv to new column `service_type` using pyspark.

The json field looks like

```
"{  \"UsageType\": \"ComputeHR\",  \"ImageType\": null,  \"ServiceType\": \"Standard_B8ms\",  \"VMName\": null,  \"VMProperties\": null,  \"VCPUs\": 8}"
```

I am using below code to do this. But I am getting empty results in new column.

```
df= df.withColumn('service_type', json_tuple(vm_records_df.additional_info_json, "ServiceType"))
```

Root cause for above situation is the json field is not correct. It is starting and ending with quotes, and it also contains backslashes. How can I remove those start and end quotes?

Comment: where do you get this string from ? what are you reading initially ?

Comment: This string we are getting in column which we are reading from csv files

Comment: does the string include double quotes at the begining or is it the python representation ?

Comment: basic python `json.loads` can be used as an UDF and should work over malformatted JSON. But it is only a workarround and has poorly performances.

Comment: What is your expected output? What is `json_tuple` above? Please provide all details to reproduce the problem. Possibly, provide a minimal reproducible example.